# I'm not able to use PySpark using a proxy configuration

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, proxy

I am using pyspark to connect to some resources that needs to be reached through a proxy configuration. I was trying several approaches in order to authenticate with the proxy configuration but I wasn't able to go through it.

If I don't use Pyspark it works just exporting the variables:

- HTTP_PROXY
- HTTPS_PROXY

But with Pyspark I tried the following approaches without success:

1. Spark context system properties:

   ```
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("http.proxyUser", <user>)
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("http.proxyPassword", <pass>)
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("http.proxyHost", <host>)
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("http.proxyPort", <port>)
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "")
   SparkContext.setSystemProperty("jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes", "")
   ```
2. SparkSession builder configuration, environment variables:

   ```
   SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name) \
      .config("spark.executorEnv.HTTP_PROXY", <URL>) \
      .config("spark.executorEnv.HTTPS_PROXY", <URL>) \
      .config("spark.driverEnv.HTTP_PROXY", <URL>) \
      .config("spark.driverEnv.HTTPS_PROXY", <URL>) \
      .config("spark.yarAppMasterEnv.HTTP_PROXY", <URL>) \
      .config("spark.yarAppMasterEnv.HTTPS_PROXY", <URL>)
   ```
3. SparkSession builder configuration, extraJavaOption:

   ```
    SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name) \
       .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "-Dhttp.proxyUser=<user> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=<pass> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyUser=<user> -Dhttps.proxyPassword=<pass> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes= -Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes= )
   ```

Approaches number 1 and 3 throw the error "*Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required*" and I don't know why it isn't working since I'm already setting the values user and password.

Comment: You are using `extraClassPath` instead of `extraJavaOptions`